# Can the reals be the union of a countable set and a set of lower cardinality?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice

Without assuming the Axiom of Choice, is the following proposition provable?

If $A$ is countable, and $|A \cup B|=|\mathbb{R}|$, then $|B|=|\mathbb{R}|$.